# WP8 TaskCompletionSource not getting Result

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webclient, taskcompletionsource

I've an extension method for WebClient (WP8)

```
public static Task<string> DownloadStringTask(this WebClient webClient, Uri uri)
    {
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
            }
            else if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                tcs.TrySetCanceled();
            }
            else
            {
                tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
            }
        };

    webClient.DownloadStringAsync(uri);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

and the call to this method

```
public string GetResult()
{
    var task = new WebClient().DownloadStringTask(new Uri("http:\\www.foo.com"));

    return task.Result;
}
```

The DownloadStringCompleted is never executed and obviously there is no result, if I press the pause button on VS always is waiting in task.Result.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `GetResult` executed from the main thread? In that case, it may be a deadlock. If I remember correctly, the callback of the `WebClient` is executed on the main thread, which cannot happen since you're blocking it by calling `task.Result`.

You have multiple ways to prevent this issue:

- Use a `HttpWebRequest` instead of a `WebClient`
- Call `GetResult` from another thread
- Execute the task asynchronously by using `task.ContinueWith` instead of directly `task.Result`
- Rewrite your method using async/await keywords

Comment: HttpClient has the very same issue with deadlock, most probably because it uses WebClient behind the scenes. Synchronous web requests are really not possible on Windows Phone, even if you're using ConfigureAwait to schedule web request's completion on other thread than the main one. Long hours spent on trying to make this work with no avail.

Comment: @Haspemulator I don't know for `HttpClient` as I haven't used it much yet, but `HttpWebRequest` should work

Comment: Calling the method from another thread solved the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`task.Result` blocks the executing thread until the result is available. For me it seems that your code just defeats the purpose of making the request asynchronous. As KooKiz mentioned, use some truly asynchronous API to get the result, such as `task.ContinueWith` or `await task`.