# How to make the return call wait for async complete c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8

I am calling into this static login method with username and password. I want it to wait to return until the downloadstringasync has completed. For the freaking life of me I cant get it to wait though.

I tried the oldschool

```
while(wc.IsBusy){} //Which froze
```

also tried a variety of async crap that didnt even compile

```
    public static dbObj Login(String username, String password)
    {
        dbObj ret = new dbObj();
        String rawWebReturn = "";
        ret.propBag.Add(_BAGTYPE,returnTypes.Login.ToString());
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(baseLoginURI + "uname=" + username + "&pword=" + password + "&date=" + date.ToString()));   


        wc.DownloadStringCompleted  += (s,e) => {                                         
                                   if(e.Error!=null)
                                      rawWebReturn = e.Error.Message;
                                   else
                                      rawWebReturn = e.Result;
                                };
        return parseWebReturn(rawWebReturn,ret);            
    }
```

Comment: If you want it to be synchronous, why not just call the synchronous method, `DownloadString`?

Comment: Because it doesnt exist in windows phone.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the platform. That tells you something though. You shouldn't be trying to block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should never ever **wait** for an asynchronous operation to finish. Instead, continue with your execution after the function completes.

**EDIT: You must add NuGet package [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) here.**

Now, since you are using Windows Phone 8, you can safely use async here:

```
    public static async dbObj Login(String username, String password)
    {
        dbObj ret = new dbObj();
        String rawWebReturn = "";
        ret.propBag.Add(_BAGTYPE, returnTypes.Login.ToString());
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        try
        {
            var result = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(baseLoginURI + "uname=" + username + "&pword=" + password + "&date=" + date.ToString()));
            return parseWebReturn(result, ret);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return parseWebReturn(e.Message, ret);
        }
    }
```

Async *must* compile because it just works. If you are having trouble with it, ask again with your code snippet here.

If you want to target Windows Phone 7, add the above mentioned NuGet package and you will be able to compile it without problems.

Comment: There is no Download String Task Ascync for windows phone in Web Client

Comment: Add reference to NuGet package **Microsoft.Bcl.Async**.

Comment: Thanks for the solid answer. I don't know why people downvoted this question when obviously so many people answered it with different solutions. It obviously has some value. Anyway good idea, saved me a huge hack (that I already implimented but now will be ripping out)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to block the thread until an async operation is completed, you can use `ManualResetEvent`, like this:

```
ManualResetEvent wait = new ManualResetEvent(false);

wc.DownloadStringCompleted  += (s,e) => {                                         
    // ...

    // allow to proceed
    wait.Set();
};

// wait until Set
wait.WaitOne();

return parseWebReturn(rawWebReturn,ret);
```

---

In general though, you don't want to block threads, but rather use callbacks.  You can do that by providing an `Action` delegate instead of the return value:

```
public static void Login(String username, String password, Action<dbObj> callback)
{
    // ...

    wc.DownloadStringCompleted  += (s,e) => {                                         
                               if(e.Error!=null)
                                  rawWebReturn = e.Error.Message;
                               else
                                  rawWebReturn = e.Result;

                               Callback(parseWebReturn(rawWebReturn, ret););
                            };
}
```

Comment: I REAAAALLLY wanted your first solution to work. However it just hangs at waitone :-(  For your second solution the return type must be dbObj

Comment: @AMR are you sure the "DownloadStringCompleted" is actually getting triggered?

Comment: It's not getting called because it's hanging on WaitOne

Comment: There is now DownloadString Completed in windows phone

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.net.webclient(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you force a wait in the UI thread either by spinning a `while` loop or using `ManualResetEvent.WaitOne` then you are actually deadlocking your app. The network call at some point appears to need to touch the UI thread, but you've frozen it = deadlock.

Freezing the UI thread like this is also bad in lots of other ways (no touch events will be processed, no screen updates etc).

You would be better off using [HttpClient for Windows Phone](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone.aspx), and using the async/await pattern. You can download this from NuGet as the Microsoft.Net.Http package.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the existing WebClient method with the help of Async and Await method something like this

```
public Task<string> GetRssFeed(string feedUrl)
{
       var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
       var client = new WebClient();
       client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
       {
             if (e.Error == null)
             {
                  tcs.SetResult(e.Result);
             }
             else
             {
                  tcs.SetException(e.Error);
             }
        };

        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(feedUrl));
        return tcs.Task;
```

}

So from doing so you can await your call until the callback come back. This is the most effective and latest way to achieve your functionality

Comment: Yes that is the best way to achieve the functionality.

Comment: Except that this is windows phone and there is no Download String Completed

Comment: Yes there is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringcompleted(v=vs.95).aspx. Supported in: Windows Phone OS 7.1, Windows Phone OS 7.0

Comment: @RakeshRNair There is no Download String Completed in Windows Phone OS 8.0 which is what is targeted and tagged above

Comment: @RakeshRNair Here is what is available http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.net.webclient(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: @AMR : Strange, You are asked for a solution to wait until the callback, And he guide in the right way too.. I don't know what is wrong with, You can go with TaskCompletion implementation in you current implementation too.

Comment: @StephanRonald I don't know how many other ways to say this. This answer doens't work. It's not supported in windows phone 8. Look at the MSDN I linked.

Comment: @ARM : I didn't tried this in my computer, I only took Laurent's Blog as reference (http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2013/01/27/using-asyncawait-with-webclient-in-windows-phone-8-or-taskcompletionsource.aspx).  The issue you are facing is not because of missing the DownloadCompleted event, It is present in windows phone 8 instead the real reason is "the callback of the WebClient is executed on the main thread, which cannot happen since you're blocking it by calling task.Result"

Comment: Please find this thread for more detail : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708646/wp8-taskcompletionsource-not-getting-result